# C How to "draw" a Binary Tree to the console

Tags: c, algorithm, layout, binary-tree

What algorithms can be used to draw a binary tree in the console? The tree is implemented in C. For example, a BST with numbers: 2 3 4 5 8 would be shown in the console as:

[image]

Comment: create a .dot file containing your nodes and edges, and render it with graphviz. Looks neat

Comment: @litb: nice.  I actually implemented a renderlist and a framebuffer and generate my own BMPs!

Comment: Please update picture :)

Comment: Here You have open source library to do what You want: https://github.com/YoussefRaafatNasry/bst-ascii-visualization

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Check out [Printing Binary Trees in Ascii](http://web.archive.org/web/20090617110918/http://www.openasthra.com/c-tidbits/printing-binary-trees-in-ascii/)

From @AnyOneElse Pastbin below:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!Code originally from /http://www.openasthra.com/c-tidbits/printing-binary-trees-in-ascii/
!!! Just saved it, cause the website is down.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Printing Binary Trees in Ascii

Here we are not going to discuss what binary trees are (please refer this, if you are looking for binary search trees), or their operations but printing them in ascii.

The below routine prints tree in ascii for a given Tree representation which contains list of nodes, and node structure is this

    struct Tree 
    {
      Tree * left, * right;
      int element;
    };

This pic illustrates what the below routine does on canvas..
ascii tree

Here is the printing routine..

    b5855d39a6b8a2735ddcaa04a404c125001 

Auxiliary routines..

    //This function prints the given level of the given tree, assuming
    //that the node has the given x cordinate.
    void print_level(asciinode *node, int x, int level) 
    {
      int i, isleft;
      if (node == NULL) return;
      isleft = (node->parent_dir == -1);
      if (level == 0) 
      {
        for (i=0; i<(x-print_next-((node->lablen-isleft)/2)); i++) 
        {
          printf(" ");
        }
        print_next += i;
        printf("%s", node->label);
        print_next += node->lablen;
      } 
      else if (node->edge_length >= level) 
      {
        if (node->left != NULL) 
        {
          for (i=0; i<(x-print_next-(level)); i++) 
          {
            printf(" ");
          }
          print_next += i;
          printf("/");
          print_next++;
        }
        if (node->right != NULL) 
        {
          for (i=0; i<(x-print_next+(level)); i++) 
          {
            printf(" ");
          }
          print_next += i;
          printf("\\");
          print_next++;
        }
      } 
      else 
      {
        print_level(node->left, 
                    x-node->edge_length-1, 
                    level-node->edge_length-1);
        print_level(node->right, 
                    x+node->edge_length+1, 
                    level-node->edge_length-1);
      }
    }


    //This function fills in the edge_length and 
    //height fields of the specified tree
    void compute_edge_lengths(asciinode *node) 
    {
      int h, hmin, i, delta;
      if (node == NULL) return;
      compute_edge_lengths(node->left);
      compute_edge_lengths(node->right);

      /* first fill in the edge_length of node */
      if (node->right == NULL && node->left == NULL) 
      {
        node->edge_length = 0;
      } 
      else 
      {
        if (node->left != NULL) 
        {
          for (i=0; i<node->left->height && i < MAX_HEIGHT; i++) 
          {
            rprofile[i] = -INFINITY;
          }
          compute_rprofile(node->left, 0, 0);
          hmin = node->left->height;
        } 
        else 
        {
          hmin = 0;
        }
        if (node->right != NULL) 
        {
          for (i=0; i<node->right->height && i < MAX_HEIGHT; i++) 
          {
            lprofile[i] = INFINITY;
          }
          compute_lprofile(node->right, 0, 0);
          hmin = MIN(node->right->height, hmin);
        } 
        else 
        {
          hmin = 0;
        }
        delta = 4;
        for (i=0; i<hmin; i++) 
        {
          delta = MAX(delta, gap + 1 + rprofile[i] - lprofile[i]);
        }

        //If the node has two children of height 1, then we allow the
        //two leaves to be within 1, instead of 2 
        if (((node->left != NULL && node->left->height == 1) ||
              (node->right != NULL && node->right->height == 1))&&delta>4) 
        {
          delta--;
        }

        node->edge_length = ((delta+1)/2) - 1;
      }

      //now fill in the height of node
      h = 1;
      if (node->left != NULL) 
      {
        h = MAX(node->left->height + node->edge_length + 1, h);
      }
      if (node->right != NULL) 
      {
        h = MAX(node->right->height + node->edge_length + 1, h);
      }
      node->height = h;
    }

    asciinode * build_ascii_tree_recursive(Tree * t) 
    {
      asciinode * node;

      if (t == NULL) return NULL;

      node = malloc(sizeof(asciinode));
      node->left = build_ascii_tree_recursive(t->left);
      node->right = build_ascii_tree_recursive(t->right);

      if (node->left != NULL) 
      {
        node->left->parent_dir = -1;
      }

      if (node->right != NULL) 
      {
        node->right->parent_dir = 1;
      }

      sprintf(node->label, "%d", t->element);
      node->lablen = strlen(node->label);

      return node;
    }


    //Copy the tree into the ascii node structre
    asciinode * build_ascii_tree(Tree * t) 
    {
      asciinode *node;
      if (t == NULL) return NULL;
      node = build_ascii_tree_recursive(t);
      node->parent_dir = 0;
      return node;
    }

    //Free all the nodes of the given tree
    void free_ascii_tree(asciinode *node) 
    {
      if (node == NULL) return;
      free_ascii_tree(node->left);
      free_ascii_tree(node->right);
      free(node);
    }

    //The following function fills in the lprofile array for the given tree.
    //It assumes that the center of the label of the root of this tree
    //is located at a position (x,y).  It assumes that the edge_length
    //fields have been computed for this tree.
    void compute_lprofile(asciinode *node, int x, int y) 
    {
      int i, isleft;
      if (node == NULL) return;
      isleft = (node->parent_dir == -1);
      lprofile[y] = MIN(lprofile[y], x-((node->lablen-isleft)/2));
      if (node->left != NULL) 
      {
        for (i=1; i <= node->edge_length && y+i < MAX_HEIGHT; i++) 
        {
          lprofile[y+i] = MIN(lprofile[y+i], x-i);
        }
      }
      compute_lprofile(node->left, x-node->edge_length-1, y+node->edge_length+1);
      compute_lprofile(node->right, x+node->edge_length+1, y+node->edge_length+1);
    }

    void compute_rprofile(asciinode *node, int x, int y) 
    {
      int i, notleft;
      if (node == NULL) return;
      notleft = (node->parent_dir != -1);
      rprofile[y] = MAX(rprofile[y], x+((node->lablen-notleft)/2));
      if (node->right != NULL) 
      {
        for (i=1; i <= node->edge_length && y+i < MAX_HEIGHT; i++) 
        {
          rprofile[y+i] = MAX(rprofile[y+i], x+i);
        }
      }
      compute_rprofile(node->left, x-node->edge_length-1, y+node->edge_length+1);
      compute_rprofile(node->right, x+node->edge_length+1, y+node->edge_length+1);
    }

Here is the asciii tree structure…

    struct asciinode_struct
    {
      asciinode * left, * right;

      //length of the edge from this node to its children
      int edge_length; 

      int height;      

      int lablen;

      //-1=I am left, 0=I am root, 1=right   
      int parent_dir;   

      //max supported unit32 in dec, 10 digits max
      char label[11];  
    };
```

output:

```
        2
       / \
      /   \
     /     \
    1       3
   / \     / \
  0   7   9   1
 /   / \     / \
2   1   0   8   8
       /
      7
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems so. Couldn't find it Google Cache or at Internet Archive Wayback machine. This could be it, I haven't tried to run it yet:  http://datastructuresblog.wordpress.com/2007/12/21/printing-binary-trees-in-ascii/

Comment: The text appears to have become corrupted, and the code link is broken.  If anybody can find the code, please help!  A link to pastebin might not be out of line...

Comment: Found it, saved it! http://pastebin.com/d3AtFKAK and http://web.archive.org/web/20071224095835/http://www.openasthra.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/binary_trees1.c

Comment: yess this one is good one, but what if I want to print something more complex. Anyone came up with something similar for B tree?

Comment: Note that the code pasted in this answer doesn't contain all of the original code. Go to the archive link to get the full code.

Comment: I ported this to JS a few years ago https://github.com/gaastonsr/treevis

Comment: Excellent code! Congrats!

Answer (score 55):

Code:

```
int _print_t(tnode *tree, int is_left, int offset, int depth, char s[20][255])
{
    char b[20];
    int width = 5;

    if (!tree) return 0;

    sprintf(b, "(%03d)", tree->val);

    int left  = _print_t(tree->left,  1, offset,                depth + 1, s);
    int right = _print_t(tree->right, 0, offset + left + width, depth + 1, s);

#ifdef COMPACT
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        s[depth][offset + left + i] = b[i];

    if (depth && is_left) {

        for (int i = 0; i < width + right; i++)
            s[depth - 1][offset + left + width/2 + i] = '-';

        s[depth - 1][offset + left + width/2] = '.';

    } else if (depth && !is_left) {

        for (int i = 0; i < left + width; i++)
            s[depth - 1][offset - width/2 + i] = '-';

        s[depth - 1][offset + left + width/2] = '.';
    }
#else
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        s[2 * depth][offset + left + i] = b[i];

    if (depth && is_left) {

        for (int i = 0; i < width + right; i++)
            s[2 * depth - 1][offset + left + width/2 + i] = '-';

        s[2 * depth - 1][offset + left + width/2] = '+';
        s[2 * depth - 1][offset + left + width + right + width/2] = '+';

    } else if (depth && !is_left) {

        for (int i = 0; i < left + width; i++)
            s[2 * depth - 1][offset - width/2 + i] = '-';

        s[2 * depth - 1][offset + left + width/2] = '+';
        s[2 * depth - 1][offset - width/2 - 1] = '+';
    }
#endif

    return left + width + right;
}

void print_t(tnode *tree)
{
    char s[20][255];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        sprintf(s[i], "%80s", " ");

    _print_t(tree, 0, 0, 0, s);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        printf("%s\n", s[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
                           .----------------------(006)-------.                 
                      .--(001)-------.                   .--(008)--.            
                 .--(-02)       .--(003)-------.       (007)     (009)          
       .-------(-06)          (002)       .--(005)                              
  .--(-08)--.                           (004)                                   
(-09)     (-07)
```

or

```
                                                  (006)                         
                           +------------------------+---------+                 
                         (001)                              (008)               
                      +----+---------+                   +----+----+            
                    (-02)          (003)               (007)     (009)          
                 +----+         +----+---------+                                
               (-06)          (002)          (005)                              
       +---------+                        +----+                                
     (-08)                              (004)                                   
  +----+----+                                                                   
(-09)     (-07)
```

Comment: +1 for the BEAUTY of recursive implementation and the output.

Comment: I tried to use this with a tree with string values. Didn't really work well, even when increasing the width variable. Also the fixed amount of lines is unfortunate.

Answer (score 20):

Some hints: the spacing between nodes at the same depth, (e.g., 2 and 4 or 3 and 8 in your example), is a function of the depth.

Each printed row consists of all nodes with the same depth, printed from the leftmost node to the rightmost node.

So you need a way to, for example, arrange your nodes in arrays of rows, according to their depth, in order of their left-most-ness.

Starting from the root node, a *breadth-first search* will visit nodes in the order of depth and left-most-ness.

Spacing between nodes can be found by finding the maximum height of the tree, using some constant width for the deepest nodes, and doubling that width for every lesser depth, so that the width for any depth = ( 1 + maxdepth - currentdepth ) * deepestwidth.

That number gives you the printed "horizontal width" of each node at any particular depth.

A left node is horizontally *positioned* in the left half of its parent's width, a righ node in the right half. You'll insert dummy spacers for any node that doesn't have parents; an easier way to do this would be to ensure that all leaves are at the same depth as the deepest node, with *blank* as their value. Obviously, you'll also have to compensate for the width of the values, perhaps by making the greatest depth's width at least as wide as the printed (decimal representaion, presumably) of he largest valued node.

Answer (score 13):

Here is one more take when a tree is implemented in array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


#define PARENT(i) ((i-1) / 2)
#define NUM_NODES 15
#define LINE_WIDTH 70

int main() {
    int tree[NUM_NODES]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5};
    int print_pos[NUM_NODES];
    int i, j, k, pos, x=1, level=0;

    print_pos[0] = 0;
    for(i=0,j=1; i<NUM_NODES; i++,j++) {
        pos = print_pos[PARENT(i)] + (i%2?-1:1)*(LINE_WIDTH/(pow(2,level+1))+1);

        for (k=0; k<pos-x; k++) printf("%c",i==0||i%2?' ':'-');
        printf("%d",tree[i]);

        print_pos[i] = x = pos+1;
        if (j==pow(2,level)) {
            printf("\n");
            level++;
            x = 1;
            j = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
                                   0
                  1-----------------------------------2
          3-----------------4                 5-----------------6
      7---------8       9---------1       2---------3       4---------5
```

Answer (score 8):

I have this little solution in c++ - it could readily be converted to c.

My solution does require a supplementary data structure to store the current node's depth within the tree (this because if you're working with an incomplete tree a given sub-tree's depth may not be consistent with it's depth in the full tree.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

namespace tree {

template<typename T>
struct node
{
  T data;
  node* l;
  node* r;
  node(T&& data_ = T()) : data(std::move(data_)), l(0), r(0) {}
};

template<typename T>
int max_depth(node<T>* n)
{
  if (!n) return 0;
  return 1 + std::max(max_depth(n->l), max_depth(n->r));
}

template<typename T>
void prt(node<T>* n)
{
  struct node_depth
  {
    node<T>* n;
    int lvl;
    node_depth(node<T>* n_, int lvl_) : n(n_), lvl(lvl_) {}
  };

  int depth = max_depth(n);

  char buf[1024];
  int last_lvl = 0;
  int offset = (1 << depth) - 1;

  // using a queue means we perform a breadth first iteration through the tree
  std::list<node_depth> q;

  q.push_back(node_depth(n, last_lvl));
  while (q.size())
  {
    const node_depth& nd = *q.begin();

    // moving to a new level in the tree, output a new line and calculate new offset
    if (last_lvl != nd.lvl)
    {
      std::cout << "\n";

      last_lvl = nd.lvl;
      offset = (1 << (depth - nd.lvl)) - 1;
    }

    // output <offset><data><offset>
    if (nd.n)
      sprintf(buf, " %*s%d%*s", offset, " ", nd.n->data, offset, " ");
    else
      sprintf(buf, " %*s", offset << 1, " ");
    std::cout << buf;

    if (nd.n)
    {
      q.push_back(node_depth(nd.n->l, last_lvl + 1));
      q.push_back(node_depth(nd.n->r, last_lvl + 1));
    }

    q.pop_front();
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
}

}

int main()
{
  typedef tree::node<int> node;
  node* head = new node();
  head->l    = new node(1);
  head->r    = new node(2);
  head->l->l = new node(3);
  head->l->r = new node(4);
  head->r->l = new node(5);
  head->r->r = new node(6);

  tree::prt(head);

  return 0;
}
```

It prints out the following:

```
        0                                                                                                
    1       2                                                                                            
  3   4   5   6
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using your solution, but there is a minor error. The second q.push_back(node_depth(nd.n->l, last_lvl + 1)) should be q.push_back(node_depth(nd.n->r, last_lvl + 1))

Comment: @sank - not sure what you're talking about - it **does** calculate the `node_depth` of the right sub-tree already. Prehaps you mistyped it when you copied it? Working code here: http://ideone.com/wrY8Vo

Answer (score 3):

Look at the output of pstree command in Linux.
It does not produce the output in the exact form that you want, but IMHO it's more readable that way.

Answer (score 3):

I second litb's recommendation.  I had to do this lately to print the VAD tree of a Windows process and I used DOT language (just print out nodes from your binary tree walking function):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language

For example, your DOT file would contains:

```
digraph graphname {
     5 -> 3;
     5 -> 8;
     3 -> 4;
     3 -> 2;
}
```

You generate the graph with dotty.exe or convert it to PNG using dot.exe.

Comment: dot is fabulous but the problem here is ASCII

Comment: Any hint about how to integrate DOT with C?

Answer (score 2):

A very simple C++ solution printing tree in horizontal direction:

```
5
  1
    5
  9
    7
    14
```

Code (`Node::print()` function is what matters):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Tree;

class Node{
public:
    Node(int val): _val(val){}
    int val(){ return _val; }
    void add(Node *temp)
    {
        if (temp->val() > _val)
        {
            if (_rchild)
                _rchild->add(temp);
            else
            {
                _rchild = temp;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (_lchild)
                _lchild->add(temp);
            else
            {
                _lchild = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    void print()
    {
        for (int ix = 0; ix < _level; ++ix) cout << ' ';
        cout << _val << endl;
        ++_level;
        if (_lchild)
        {
            _lchild->print();
            --_level;
        }
        if (_rchild)
        {
            _rchild->print();
            --_level;
        }
    }
private:
    int _val;
    Node *_lchild;      
    Node *_rchild;
    static int _level;      
};

int Node::_level = 0;       

class Tree{
public:
    Tree(): _root(0){}  
    void add(int val)
    {
        Node *temp = new Node(val);
        if (!_root)
            _root = temp;
        else
            _root->add(temp);       
    }
    void print()
    {
        if (!_root)
            return;
        _root->print();             
    }
private:
    Node *_root;    
};

int main()
{
    Tree tree;
    tree.add(5);
    tree.add(9);
    tree.add(1);
    tree.add(7);
    tree.add(5);
    tree.add(14);
    tree.print();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't code that yourself, but have a look at [Tree::Visualize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tree-Visualize/lib/Tree/Visualize.pm) which seems to be a nice Perl implementation with different possible styles and use/port one of the algorithms there.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a Ruby program that calculates the coordinates where each node in a binary tree should be drawn here: http://hectorcorrea.com/Blog/Drawing-a-Binary-Tree-in-Ruby

This code uses a very basic algorithm to calculate the coordinates and it's not "area efficient" but it's a good start. If you want to the see the code "live" you can test it here: http://binarytree.heroku.com/

Comment: ASCII! The question asks for ASCII.

Comment: @Norman - yes indeed, but he is also asking for an *algorithm* too and he can find that on the post that I listed.