# How to print the nodes in bst whose grandparent is a multiple of five?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm sorry that was my first time for asking question in stackoverflow. I just read the faq and knew I disobeyed the rules. I was not just coping and pasting the questions. I use an in-order traverse method to do the recursion and check whether the node is a multiple of five and I don't know what to do next. Should I use a flag to check something?

```
void findNodes(BSTNode<Key,E> *root) const
{
    if(root==NULL) return;
    else
    {
        if(root->key()%5==0)//I know it's wrong, but I don't know what to do
        {
            findNodes(root->left());
            cout<<root->key()<<" ";
            findNodes(root->right());
        }
        else
        {
            findNodes(root->left());
            findNodes(root->right());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You're supposed to have your ``BSTNode`` struct like this: ``struct BSTNode { int key; BSTNode *left,*right,*parent; ... }``

Comment: no pointer to parent, my struct is like this struct BSTNode { int key; BSTNode *left,*right; }, I use a class to generate BSTNode, so the left and right are functions in my program.

Comment: It may help to think of it differently by rephrasing the question.  Print the grandchildren of all nodes that are multiples of 5.

Comment: @RogerZhu may I ask you, what's wrong with the code I put?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing nodes whose grandparent is a multiple of 5 is complicated as you have to look "up" the tree. It is easier if you look at the problem as find all the nodes who are a multiple of 5 and print their grandchildren, as you only have to go down the tree.

```
void printGrandChildren(BSTNode<Key,E> *root,int level) const{
    if(!root) return;
    if(level == 2){
         cout<<root->key()<<" ";
         return;


    }else{
        printGrandChildren(root->left(),level+1);
        printGrandChildren(root->right(),level+1);

     }

}
```

Then modify your findNodes to

```
void findNodes(BSTNode<Key,E> *root) const
{
    if(root==NULL) return;
    else
    {
        if(root->key()%5==0)
        {
            printGrandChildren(root,0);
        }
        else
        {
            findNodes(root->left());
            findNodes(root->right());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int arr[height_of_the_tree]; //arr[10000000] if needed;

void findNodes(BSTNode<Key,E> *root,int level) const {
  if(root==NULL) return;
  arr[level] = root -> key();
  findNodes(root -> left(), level + 1);
  if(2 <= level && arr[level - 2] % 5 == 0) cout << root->key() << " ";
  findNodes(root -> right(), level + 1);
}

int main() {
  ...
  findNodes(Binary_search_tree -> root,0);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to print our all child nodes which have an ancestor which has a key which is a multiple of 5, then one way would be to pass a `bool` to your findNodes function which stores this fact.

Something along the lines of:

```
void findNodes(BSTNode<Key,E>* node, bool ancesterIsMultOf5) const
{
    if (node)
    {
        if (ancesterIsMultOf5)
            std::cout << node->key() << std::endl;

        ancesterIsMultOf5 |= (node->key() % 5 == 0); 

        findNodes(node->left(), ancesterIsMultOf5);            
        findNodes(node->right(), ancesterIsMultOf5);            
    }
}
```

Alternately, if you're trying to *draw* the tree, it has been answered before: [C How to "draw" a Binary Tree to the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801740/c-how-to-draw-a-binary-tree-to-the-console/8551044)

Comment: This will print nodes whose parent is a multiple of 5, not nodes whose grandparent is multiple of 5.

Comment: great method, but I think the line  ancesterIsMultOf5 |= node->key() % 5;  should modify. IF the node->key() is 10, then the mod operation would make ancesterIsMultOf5 to false whichi is not the right value. And that's the nodes whose parent value is multiply of 5.

Comment: @RogerZhu - sorry, you are right - I have updated it to be `(node->key() % 5 == 0)`; note that I `OR` the value, so that a `false` will not reset the `bool` if it was previously `true`

Comment: @user93353 - yes, not sure Roger wants *any* ancestor, or in fact it *must* be a grandparent?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following

```
    cout<<root->key()<<" ";
```

with

```
    if(root->left)
    {
        if(root->left->left)
            cout<<root->left->left->key()<< " ";
        if(root->left->right)
            cout<<root->left->right->key()<< " ";
    }
    if(root->right)
    {
        if(root->right->left)
            cout<<root->right->left->key()<< " ";
        if(root->right->right)
            cout<<root->right->right->key()<< " ";

    }
```