# want to create tree node and print following pattern on console

Tags: java

[image]
         B1
      A1
    A    B2
         C1 
      A2
         C2

**Want to print this pattern dynamically.
What i tried is using node to represent the positions say left,right**

```
        Node<Integer> root = new Node<Integer>(2);
        Node<Integer> n11 = new Node<Integer>(7);
        Node<Integer> n12 = new Node<Integer>(5);
        Node<Integer> n21 = new Node<Integer>(2);
        Node<Integer> n22 = new Node<Integer>(6);
        Node<Integer> n23 = new Node<Integer>(3);
        Node<Integer> n24 = new Node<Integer>(6);
        Node<Integer> n31 = new Node<Integer>(5);
        Node<Integer> n32 = new Node<Integer>(8);
        Node<Integer> n33 = new Node<Integer>(4);
        Node<Integer> n34 = new Node<Integer>(5);
        Node<Integer> n35 = new Node<Integer>(8);
        Node<Integer> n36 = new Node<Integer>(4);
        Node<Integer> n37 = new Node<Integer>(5);
        Node<Integer> n38 = new Node<Integer>(8);

        root.left = n11;
        root.right = n12;

        n11.left = n21;
        n11.right = n22;
        n12.left = n23;
        n12.right = n24;

        n21.left = n31;
        n21.right = n32;
        n22.left = n33;
        n22.right = n34;
        n23.left = n35;
        n23.right = n36;
        n24.left = n37;
        n24.right = n38;
```

the program should accept the position as dynamically

Comment: Can you please provide more details, what all inputs program will take, i guess you need to tell node name and then its position ?

Comment: company have one child director.Director have 2 child manager1,manager2.Each manager have 2 asst.manager and so on..i want to print this on tree manner

Comment: any of this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801740/c-how-to-draw-a-binary-tree-to-the-console

Comment: I do not understand the last sentence. What position? Is it argument?

Comment: i mean the tree element location

Comment: Sorry I cannot imagine how you define element location in tree. Please give concrete example.

Comment: friend i added a image on my post take a look at that...
done with swing i want its background details..!