# Drawing a binary tree to console in c

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal, inorder

I'd just like to note I already saw this post before asking my question: [C How to "draw" a Binary Tree to the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801740/c-how-to-draw-a-binary-tree-to-the-console)

Let's say I have the following tree. If my print function were to print only the numbers (in order traversal), I would have the following printed out: 1,3,4,6,7,8,10,13,14.

What would be the best approach to draw the tree like something below considering the tree gets printed in that order?

I feel that if 8 got printed first followed by 3,10 etc.. it would be easier but since it is in-order traversal 1 is getting printed first which would be the first print statement at the top.

[image]

Comment: in-order traversal (listed it in the line above)

Comment: Right, so you want to know how to do an in order traversal of the tree. Try doing a search for "binary tree in order traversal". There are lots of existing guides for that within and outside SO.

Answer (score 0):

I did this about 2 years ago for some coursework...

I created a node struct that contained its own data and 2 nodes, one left and one right, it looked like this (I couldn't find the final code, that might have used shared pointers):

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};
```

I then created my tree by adding more nodes to it using recursion like so:

```
void insert(node **tree, int value)
{
    if (*tree == nullptr)
    {
        *tree = new node;
        (*tree)->data = value;
        (*tree)->left = nullptr;
        (*tree)->right = nullptr;
    }
    else if (value < (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&((*tree)->left), value);//memory location of the pointer to the node of the node
    }
    else if (value > (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&((*tree)->right), value);
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

Side note: Looking back, I never accounted for adding a node with the same value as an existing node if that's even possible.

I assume you will be doing something similar. Now for the bit that answers your question, printing it out, also using recursion.

```
void inorder(node *tree)
{
    if (!(tree == nullptr))
    {
        inorder((tree)->left);
        cout << (tree->data) << endl;//Prints on new lines, you could comma separate them if you really wanted.
        inorder((tree)->right);
    }
}
```

Lastly, you'll want to clean up your tree after you've used it so you'll need to delete it... *recursively*.

To be honest it's been a while and this recursion thing is still a little confusing to me so I have probably forgotten something, but the theory's there!

Edit, headers used: `<iostream>` and `<memory>`, also this was `c++` not `c` but they're very similar.